Apache ModSecurity, OWASP with WordPress and Roundcube plugin – how to divide this up between the virtual hosts?

Apache/2.4.62 (Debian)
ModSecurity 2.9.7-1+b1
OWASP coreruleset-4.6.0

I have secured my Apache web server with ModSecurity and the OWASP ruleset. This works very well so far and a test SQL injection is also detected and rejected.
Now I have several virtual hosts. Some run Wordpress, one runs Roundcube and some run normal HTML pages without anything behind them.
How can I configure it so that the OWASP Wordpress plugin is only used for the virtual hosts with WordPress installation, and the OWASP Roundcube plugin only for the Roundcube host and all other hosts use the standard ruleset?
